# Segmentation Fault in a BST of strings

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

So, I'm doing an assignment for a class in college and the objective is to construct a BST of strings that read a text, divides it and insert each word in the Tree.

But I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to insert a word (manually), can you guys show me where I did wrong and suggest a repair?

```
/* Structure for the node */
typedef struct node {
  char *key;
  int multi;
  struct node *left, *right;
} node;

node *root;

void Insert(char *x, node *p){
    p = root;

  /* if the pointer points to null, create a new node and insert the key */
  if (*p == NULL){
    (*p) = (node)malloc(sizeof(node))
    (*p)->key = strcpy((*p)->key, x);
    (*p)->left = NULL;
    (*p)->right = NULL;
    return;
  }
  else if (strcasecmp(x, p->key) < 0)
  { 
    Insert(x, &p->left);
    return;
  }

  else if (strcasecmp(x, p->key) > 0)
  {
    Insert(x, &p->right);
    return;
  }
  /* if the words are equal, add 1 to the multi (how many times the word appears */
  else
    (*p)->multi = multi + 1;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile! When you declare `p` as a pointer you can't do e.g. `(*p)->key...` And then just a little later you use it correctly, e.g. `p->key`.

Comment: Also, why pass in `p` as an argument and directly reassign it to point to `root`?

Comment: This code is frankly a mountain of undefined behavior. The (**unnecessary**) hard cast from `malloc()` to a type that isn't even a pointer-type is the only thing saving this from failing to even compile. And it *rapidly* goes downhill from there.

Comment: I'm sorry, my code was in another language (not english) and I had to make several corrections to make it understandable, and some mistakes were made in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problematic statement: `(*p)->key = strcpy((*p)->key, x);` You allocated memory only for `node` but the pointer `key` is still uninitialized. You need to allocate memory for `key` also, something like `(*p)->key = malloc(strlen(x) + 1);`.